# Is there a way to plot Nullclines of a nonlinear system of ODEs

Tags: python, plot, spyder, ode

So I am trying to plot the nullclines of a system of ODEs, however I can't seem to plot them in the correct way. When I plot them, I manage to plot them according to time (t vs x and t vs y) but not at (x vs y). I'm not really sure how to explain it, and I think it would be better to just show it. [I am trying to replicate this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onzMM.png) The equations and parameters are given, however this was done in a program called XPP (I'll post these at the bottom), and there are some parameters that i don't understand what they mean.

My entire code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define system in terms of a Numpy array
def Sys(X, t=0):
    # here X[0] = x and x[1] = y    
    #protien [] is represented with y, and mRNA [] is represented by x
    return np.array([ (k1*S*Kd**p)/(Kd**p + X[1]**p) - kdx*X[0],  ksy*X[0] - (k2*ET*X[1])/(Km + X[1])])



#variables
k1=.1
S=1
Kd=1
kdx=.1
p=2
ksy=1
k2=1
ET=1
Km=1



# generate 1000 linearly spaced numbers for x-axes
t = np.linspace(0, 50,100)
# initial values
Sys0 = np.array([1, 0])

#Solves the ODE
X, infodict = integrate.odeint(Sys, Sys0, t, full_output = 1, mxstep = 50000)


#assigns appropriate equations to x and y
x,y = X.T

#plot's the graph
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.5, hspace = 0.3)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)

ax1.plot(x, color="blue")
ax1.plot(y, color = 'red')

ax1.set_xlabel("Protien concentration")
ax1.set_ylabel("mRNA concentration")  
ax1.set_title("Phase space")
ax1.grid()
```

The given equations and parameters are:

model for a simple negative feedback loop

protein (y) inhibits the synthesis of its mRNA (x)

dx/dt = k1*S*Kd^p/(Kd^p + y^p) - kdx*x

dy/dt = ksy*x - k2*ET*y/(Km + y)

p k1=0.1, S=1, Kd=1, kdx=0.1, p=2

p ksy=1, k2=1, ET=1, Km=1

@ XP=y, YP=x, TOTAL=100, METH=stiff, XLO=0, XHI=4, YLO=0, YHI=1.05 (I don't exactly understand what is going on here)

Again, this uses a program called XPP or WINPP.
Any help with this would be appreciated, the original paper I am trying to replicate this from is : Design principles of biochemical oscillators by Bela Novak and John J. Tyson

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am only tying to graph the green and red lines.

Comment: You could use the contour plot facilities of matplolib. In the options you can determine what levels to draw, and also give different styles for these levels.